# Convert Object to Array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to convert:

```
{
 0: 'a',
 1: 'b',
 2: 'c'
},
 {
 0: 'd',
 1: 'e',
 2: 'f'
}
```

to:

```
[ [a [b,c] ], [d [e,f] ] ]
```

where the `0 property` of objects have the array of `1 and 2` objects? Is there a way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var data = [{
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c'
}, {
    0: 'd',
    1: 'e',
    2: 'f',
    3: 'g'
}];

var result = data.map(function (obj) {
    var subArr = Object.keys(obj).slice(1).map(function(key) {
        return obj[key];
    });
    return [obj[0], subArr];
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Above function use the element at index 0 as the first item of the nested arrays, and everything else in the subarray.

Comment: hi, what if I have thousands of data objects. ? It means I need to map them 1 by 1?

Comment: You mean that you can have not 3 but arbitrary number of elements in nested objects?

Comment: Check generic implementation.

Comment: Can I ask you some. Is there any other way to do it without using map function?

Comment: Yes, you can loop with `for (var key in obj) { subArr.push(obj[key]) }`.

Comment: can you give example how to do it. ? Thanks in advance